# RabbitMQ custom table source and sink for pyflink 1.11

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-flink, ddl, pyflink

According to the docs here:

`https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/connectors/`

and

`https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/connectors/`

is it possible to create a custom ddl RabbitMQ connector to be used in pyflink TABLE API 1.11?

how?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to implement your custom connector implementation based on the interface provided by Java. Then you need to use the API or command line parameters to refer to the jar used which you can refer to
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/python/common_questions.html#adding-jar-files